# Upstart/uWSGI/Flask doesn't log exceptions

Tags: flask, wsgi, upstart

I have the following config file for Upstart, and it starts the Flask server fine, but whenever there is an exception in the app the log file doesn't have the exception information.

```
start on [2345]
stop on [06]
respawn
script
    cd /var/www/binary-fission/server
    export BF_CONFIG=config/staging.py
    exec uwsgi --http 0.0.0.0:5000 --wsgi-file server.py --callable app --master --threads 2 --processes 4 --logto /var/log/binary-fission/server.log
end script
```

However, if I run the same uwsgi command manually without Upstart, the exception is logged.

How do I make upstart+uwgi log the exception from a Flask application?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that turning on the "PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS" option in the flask configuration file (config/staging.py) fixed the issue. This is because in that configuration file, "DEBUG" is turned off which turns "PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS" off at the same time.

When I ran uwsgi command manually, I didn't specify the configuration file and my Flask app fell back to the default configuration with "DEBUG" on.